# Setting up Google-api-java-client developing environment

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api-java-client

I am trying the official example **calendar-v2-atom-android**. I have already import all dependency by using maven and it compile successfully. However, in run time , no class def found error occurs when it comes to

> private final List calendars = Lists.newArrayList();
>
> private final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

It seems that it can't find the class in library in runtime.

What should I do in eclipse?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding yet?

Comment: yes, many times.
Btw, should I use Maven Build in Run Configuration?
After I download all dependency using Maven,I just build it like usual android application instead of using "Maven Build".

Comment: Regular "build" never worked for me in android maven project, though "clean and build" worked pretty well.

Comment: But I try clean and then build many times....
It can compile but cannot run!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the Google Api Java Client

Create a libs folder in your eclipse project.

Drag and drop all client files that do not end in -source into the libs folder you just made.
Do not add the dependencies folder, instead drag the dependencies from inside the folder to the libs folder.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab

Click Add JARS, navigate to your libs folder and add all of the client files.

Click the Order and Export tab and check off all the client files you added.

Clean the project.
You should be good to go.

**Update**

As of ADT Rev. 21, the setup works as follows:

1. Create a libs folder in your eclipse project
2. Drag and drop all client files that do not end in -source into the libs folder you just made. Do not add the dependencies folder, instead drag the dependencies from inside the folder to the libs folder.
3. Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export Tab
4. Check off the box for "Android Private Libraries" and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes.  Very much needed answer!