# Google place API integration

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using sample code for google place api from [GitHub](https://github.com/tuthan/Google-Place-Api-Demo)

And, having following error while am using above Example -

> ```
> Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport', referenced from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.<clinit>
> Could not find class 'hung.vo.PlaceRequest$1', referenced from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.createRequestFactory
> Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method hung.vo.PlaceRequest.performSearch
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: hung.vo.PlaceRequest 
> hung.vo.hung.vo.GooglePlaceActivity$SearchSrv.doInBackground(GooglePlaceActivity.java:36)
> ```

and in **GooglePlaceActivity line 36** is

```
pl = new PlaceRequest().performSearch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, The Project which you are referring its  a **Maven Project**, so you can't add it as a simple **Android Project** in your Eclipse Workspace (I hope you are using Eclipse). For this you have to use [**Eclipse - Maven Plugin**](http://www.roseindia.net/maven2/maven_2_eclipse_plugin.shtml) in your Eclipse and import this project as a **import Existing Maven Project**.. When you build this Project as a **Maven Build** then It will automatically resolved all dependencies jar file by including them (You don't have to add manually it). And then it will run as a Android Project.

Else refer this Tutorial [Introducing the Google Places API](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html) with nice explanation.

Also You can only use source of above project and add Manually [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list) to your android project's build path without using as a Maven Project.

Comment: thanks for reply. i am implementing your solutions and will let u know if its working.

Comment: 1st: when tried to add maven plugin in eclipse it shows- could not found http://mevenide.codehaus.org/repository, 2nd: i m already refering this tutorial, 3rd: tried this but still same error as i mentiond above.. :( :( plz help me out.

Comment: Make a android project same as github source add necessary packages and resources, layout files and then download google-place-client library and add it in project build path..

Comment: Because, to install maven plugin it quite difficult. Also if possible from Eclipse, help -> install software update -> eclipse market place and then add Maven plugins from it..

Comment: yeahh.. i had done like this. made a new android project, add packages, src, layout files from github source, then added google-place-client library to build path.. but error still same .. its sucks me frm last two days :(

Comment: project right click > properties > java build path > add external jars> then selected all jar files and click on Ok

Answer (score 0):

Download the Google Api Java Client

Create a libs folder in your eclipse project.

Drag and drop all client files that do not end in -source into the libs folder you just made. Do not add the dependencies folder, instead drag the dependencies from inside the folder to the libs folder.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab

Click Add JARS, navigate to your libs folder and add all of the client files.

Click the Order and Export tab and check off all the client files you added.

Clean the project. You should be good to go.

See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595808/add-external-jar-to-android-project-in-eclipse) it's the same problem as yours.