# Including a Jar in Android App

Tags: java, android, jar, import

I want to include a jar into my Android package.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I followed several explanations, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285306/setting-up-google-api-java-client-developing-environment/7370807#7370807), but I still get `NoClassDefFoundError`s - at runtime, building, compiling, installing the project worked without errors.

Most answers seem to be outdated. How do I solve this issue using the current Eclipse, ADT and Android versions? Adding them to the Java Build Path like in plain Java projects didn't help.

All help appreciated.

What I have tried

- Putting them into a folder and including into the project [[Screenshot]](http://s14.directupload.net/images/130331/n3wenzv2.png)

Comment: you need to clean the project and re-build.

Comment: tried, didn't made it...

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar in a folder entitled 'libs' (should be in the root of your project. Then add it to the java build path.

If that doesn't work try this:

1. Your Project -> right click -> Import -> File System -> yourjar.jar
2. Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> yourjar.ja

Comment: Tried with a sample project, but failed. I used a small jar containing one class, and the App only contains a main activity. Could you set me a simple application up and set it to me? Something must be terrible wrong at my ADT installation...

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? I don't think it would be anything wrong with your ADT installation...

Comment: Yes, I tried cleaning and rebuilding both projects, but it didn't help. I've also tried debugging via an AVD (instead of my SGS2, running Android 4.1.2), but it didn't help as well.

Comment: Hmm that is odd... Well unless anyone  has a better idea maybe you should try reinstalling ADT

Comment: I reinstalled the ADT bundle but IT STILL DOES NOT WORK -.- I exported the project as a zip... All help appreciated: http://uploaded.net/file/6ubiwq5f

Comment: Well I'm afraid I have no idea... Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I have tried every one of the suggestions above and they all worked for me...

Comment: Maybe you can make a valid project and export it as zip for me? In that way I can make sure that I didn't make anything wrong with the project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add your jars to libs folder. Automatically add's those JARs to your compile-time build path. More importantly, it will put the contents of the JARs into your APK file, so they will be part of your run-time build path.

Answer (score 0):

You two things and the error will be fixed

1. Right click on Project-->Select Properties-->Go to Java Build Path--> Select 3rd tab from top i.e "Libraries" -->Click Add Jar--> Select your Jar
2. Right click on Project-->Select Properties-->Go to Java Build Path--> Select 4th tab from top i.e "Order and Export" --> Select(chekbox) your Jar.

For more help check this [link](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2012/06/noclassdeffounderror-after-updating-adt.html)